# relative paths for outDir and rootDir in a base tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript

I have a base `tsconfig.json` where I want to have all consistent properties for all projects that reference it.

I was hoping I could persistently put the `outDir`, `rootDir`, `include` and `excludes` here:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "removeComments": false,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./dist",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately

```js
{
  "extends": "../frontend-common/typescript/tsconfig.base.json",
}
```

But when I try and compile a project, I get this error:

> error TS6059: File 'blah.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/path/to/tsconfig.base.json/dir'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

File paths in `tsconfig.base.json` are probably unsurprisingly relative to that file's location.

Is there any way of making them relative to the `tsconfig.json` that references the base `tsconfig.base.json`?

It is annoying to have this in each `tsconfig.json`

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./dist",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for something similar, but as of now there is no way to do the same.

Reference issue - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29172